# google calendar API not working

Tags: python, calendar, oauth-2.0

I am just trying to get my code to grab any data from my calendar.
I am using python with the google api python client to access the calendar api.

This is the code for the homepage

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/py.py')
authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
print '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url='+authorize_url+'">'
```

all what it does is that redirects it to the consent page.

And this is the page it redirects go "py.py"

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
import re
import httplib2,urllib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
def getCode(parameters):
    try:
            return re.search('code=(.*)',parameters).group(1)
    except:
            return False
FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/py.py')

currentUrl=os.environ['REQUEST_URI']
code=getCode(currentUrl)

credentials = FLOW.step2_exchange(code)

http=httplib2.Http()
http=credentials.authorize(http)
calendar = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
print calendar.calendarList().list().to_json()
```

This is the output for the print in the end

```
{"body": null, "resumable_uri": null, "headers": {"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate", "accept": "application/json", "user-agent": "google-api-python-client/1.3.2 (gzip)"}, "uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?alt=json", "resumable": null, "methodId": "calendar.calendarList.list", "body_size": 0, "resumable_progress": 0, "method": "GET", "_in_error_state": false, "response_callbacks": []}
```

I have read every page about Oauth2.0 and the calendar API for python on google's developer page. I tried to google alot. I have been stuck on this code for a week now.

information about the calendar.calenderList().list() method:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/calendar/v3/calendar.calendarList.list

Comment: Try changing `print calendar.calendarList().list().to_json()` to `print calendar.calendarList().list().execute()`

Comment: That worked, post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.
can you give me some explanation though?